# Making an 'anim in circular motion' get attracted by gravity of the center

Tags: unity, physics, motion, path

I am working on a project, where the main player anim is in circular motion with respect to a center point. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXIaeTKarDo) shows what I have done to the anim till now.

In that video, there are multiple apples are in circular motion. However, in my case, there is only one anim which is in circular motion. I have tried the following code for the circular motion.

```
public Transform center;
public float degreesPerSecond = -65.0f;

private Vector3 v;

void Start() {
    v = transform.position - center.position;
}

void Update () {
    v = Quaternion.AngleAxis (degreesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.forward) * v;
    transform.position = center.position + v;
}
```

The above code works perfect for the circular motion.

At the center (0, 0), I placed a circle sprite with 'point effector 2d' component. (see below image).[image: Inspector details of the centre sprite]

The reason why I 'added point effector 2d ' is to apply gravity effect to the player. But that didn't work. The player anim which is in circular motion around the circle sprite should get affected by gravity of that circle sprite and it should be pulled towards the center.

Changing the 'Point effector 2d' parameters is good enough to create gravity? or do I require any change in code?